# Stroke line array on canvas at mouse position

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to relatively stroke a line on a canvas at my mouse coordinates.

So when clicked, draw the line array at your mouse coordinates.

Example:
I have a canvas with this line stroke

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var linearray = [
  { x: 195, y: 104 },
  { x: 197, y: 104 },
  { x: 201, y: 102 },
  { x: 203, y: 100 },
  { x: 205, y: 98 },
  { x: 206, y: 103 },
  { x: 206, y: 106 },
  { x: 207, y: 108 },
  { x: 211, y: 106 },
  { x: 214, y: 103 },
  { x: 216, y: 102 },
  { x: 216, y: 102 }
];

function strokeArrayPoints(point, index) {
    ctx.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
    ctx.stroke();
}

linearray.forEach(strokeArrayPoints);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="600" style="border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
```

How could I simply reposition the coordinates of this array so I can relatively stroke it anywhere my mouse clicks on a canvas.

Below you can see what I've tried, and get the basic concept of what I'm trying to achieve:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var x = 0;
var y = 0;

var linearray = [
  { x: 195, y: 104 },
  { x: 197, y: 104 },
  { x: 201, y: 102 },
  { x: 203, y: 100 },
  { x: 205, y: 98 },
  { x: 206, y: 103 },
  { x: 206, y: 106 },
  { x: 207, y: 108 },
  { x: 211, y: 106 },
  { x: 214, y: 103 },
  { x: 216, y: 102 },
  { x: 216, y: 102 }
];

function strokeArrayPoints(point, index) {
  ctx.lineTo(point.x + x, point.y + y);
  ctx.stroke();
}

c.addEventListener(
  "click",
  function (e) {
    console.log(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    x = e.clientX;
    y = e.clientY;

    ctx.moveTo(x, y);
    linearray.forEach(strokeArrayPoints);
  },
  false
 );
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="600" style="border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're really close! The main thing that needs to be done is the points need to be set relatively to 0 first, then we can add the mouse position.

We can do this by subtracting the `x` and `y` of the first element in the `linearray`. Note it doesn't have to be set on the first point either, you could choose the middle of the array to get the difference from. In the end all we're doing is translating our points to be based on `0, 0`.

- The first point will become `0, 0`
- The second point will become `2, 0`
- The third point will become `6, -2`

Then when we apply the offset of the mouse position it will add the mouse position as the offset.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var x = 0;
var y = 0;

var linearray = [
  { x: 195, y: 104 },
  { x: 197, y: 104 },
  { x: 201, y: 102 },
  { x: 203, y: 100 },
  { x: 205, y: 98 },
  { x: 206, y: 103 },
  { x: 206, y: 106 },
  { x: 207, y: 108 },
  { x: 211, y: 106 },
  { x: 214, y: 103 },
  { x: 216, y: 102 },
  { x: 216, y: 102 }
];

function strokeArrayPoints(point, index, arr) {
  // Make points relative to our reference. This is probably better put somewhere outside
  // of this function, just here for readability.
  const relX = point.x - arr[0].x;
  const relY = point.y - arr[0].y;
  
  ctx.lineTo(relX + x, relY + y);
  ctx.stroke();
}

c.addEventListener(
  "click",
  function (e) {
    console.log(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    x = e.clientX;
    y = e.clientY;

    ctx.moveTo(x, y);
    linearray.forEach(strokeArrayPoints);
  },
  false
 );
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="600" style="border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
```

Comment: I knew I was pretty close to getting it. Thanks for finding a solution Loktar. This will certainly help me in the future too.

Comment: Loktar, can you help me with this problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67276897/drawing-relative-line-coordinates-from-array-on-canvas