# Draw line array relatively on canvas

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas, mouse

Hello I'm having some trouble with drawing 3 lines on a canvas relatively to my mouse click.

The 3 lines make a small smiley face.

So in my code I have a function called **parseRecordedLinePoints()**, In this function it makes the points from each line relative to my mouse, then strokes it on the canvas.

For some reason when it's called and strokes the canvas, the eyes get stroked above each other. (overlaps)

I've tried to fix it by changing the function to:

```
    function parseRecordedLinePoints(Point, index, arr) {
      ctx.lineTo(Point.x, Point.y);
      ctx.stroke();
    }
```

When the function is like this it draws the smiley, but not relatively and the lines connect to each other.

Here's the code currently as an snippet, so you can get a better look. You can see how it draws the eyes in the wrong position, and overlaps them directly under my mouse. I'm trying to make it draw the smiley face correctly relatively.

**CODE:**

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var cursorX = 100; //Example position X
var cursorY = 0; //Example position Y

var relX = 0;
var relY = 0;

//3 lines // A smiley face.
var recordedLines = [{
        Color: {
            r: 0,
            g: 50,
            b: 0
        },
        LinePoints: [{
                x: 125,
                y: 370.2
            },
            {
                x: 125,
                y: 367.9
            },
            {
                x: 127.2,
                y: 365.7
            },
            {
                x: 128.4,
                y: 367.9
            },
            {
                x: 127.2,
                y: 370.2
            },
            {
                x: 125,
                y: 371.3
            },
            {
                x: 122.8,
                y: 370.2
            },
            {
                x: 121.7,
                y: 367.9
            },
            {
                x: 121.7,
                y: 364.6
            },
            {
                x: 123.9,
                y: 363.5
            },
            {
                x: 127.2,
                y: 363.5
            },
            {
                x: 128.4,
                y: 365.7
            },
            {
                x: 128.4,
                y: 369
            },
            {
                x: 126.1,
                y: 370.2
            },
            {
                x: 123.9,
                y: 369
            },
            {
                x: 122.8,
                y: 366.8
            },
            {
                x: 123.9,
                y: 364.6
            },
            {
                x: 127.2,
                y: 364.6
            },
            {
                x: 127.2,
                y: 367.9
            },
            {
                x: 125,
                y: 369
            },
            {
                x: 123.9,
                y: 366.8
            },
            {
                x: 123.9,
                y: 366.8
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        Color: {
            r: 100,
            g: 0,
            b: 0
        },
        LinePoints: [{
                x: 168.4,
                y: 365.7
            },
            {
                x: 166.1,
                y: 366.8
            },
            {
                x: 163.9,
                y: 363.5
            },
            {
                x: 166.1,
                y: 362.4
            },
            {
                x: 168.4,
                y: 363.5
            },
            {
                x: 167.2,
                y: 365.7
            },
            {
                x: 163.9,
                y: 365.7
            },
            {
                x: 163.9,
                y: 362.4
            },
            {
                x: 165,
                y: 360.2
            },
            {
                x: 168.4,
                y: 360.2
            },
            {
                x: 169.5,
                y: 363.5
            },
            {
                x: 168.4,
                y: 365.7
            },
            {
                x: 165,
                y: 365.7
            },
            {
                x: 163.9,
                y: 363.5
            },
            {
                x: 165,
                y: 360.2
            },
            {
                x: 168.4,
                y: 360.2
            },
            {
                x: 168.4,
                y: 363.5
            },
            {
                x: 168.4,
                y: 364.6
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        Color: {
            r: 100,
            g: 0,
            b: 0
        },
        LinePoints: [{
                x: 107.2,
                y: 377.9
            },
            {
                x: 109.5,
                y: 379
            },
            {
                x: 110.6,
                y: 381.3
            },
            {
                x: 112.8,
                y: 382.4
            },
            {
                x: 115,
                y: 384.6
            },
            {
                x: 117.2,
                y: 386.8
            },
            {
                x: 119.5,
                y: 387.9
            },
            {
                x: 122.8,
                y: 389
            },
            {
                x: 126.1,
                y: 390.2
            },
            {
                x: 129.5,
                y: 391.3
            },
            {
                x: 132.8,
                y: 391.3
            },
            {
                x: 136.1,
                y: 391.3
            },
            {
                x: 139.5,
                y: 392.4
            },
            {
                x: 142.8,
                y: 392.4
            },
            {
                x: 146.1,
                y: 392.4
            },
            {
                x: 149.5,
                y: 392.4
            },
            {
                x: 152.8,
                y: 392.4
            },
            {
                x: 156.1,
                y: 391.3
            },
            {
                x: 159.5,
                y: 390.2
            },
            {
                x: 161.7,
                y: 389
            },
            {
                x: 165,
                y: 389
            },
            {
                x: 167.2,
                y: 387.9
            },
            {
                x: 169.5,
                y: 386.8
            },
            {
                x: 171.7,
                y: 385.7
            },
            {
                x: 173.9,
                y: 384.6
            },
            {
                x: 176.1,
                y: 383.5
            },
            {
                x: 178.4,
                y: 382.4
            },
            {
                x: 179.5,
                y: 380.2
            },
            {
                x: 181.7,
                y: 379
            },
            {
                x: 182.8,
                y: 376.8
            },
            {
                x: 183.9,
                y: 375.7
            }
        ]
    }
];

//----------------------------------
//var relativeARRAY = []; //recordedLines array, but relative to mouse.
//var color = [{ r: 0, g: 0, b: 0 }];

function parseRecordedLinePoints(Point, index, arr) {
    relX = Point.x - arr[0].x;
    relY = Point.y - arr[0].y;

    ctx.lineTo(relX + cursorX, relY + cursorY);
    ctx.stroke();
}

//----------------------------------
function parseRecordedLine(Line, index, arr) {
    const LinePoints = Line.LinePoints;

    //-- parse the x and y points of this line.. to make relative..
    LinePoints.forEach(parseRecordedLinePoints);
}
//----------------------------------

c.addEventListener(
    "click",
    function(e) {
        cursorX = e.clientX;
        cursorY = e.clientY;

        ctx.moveTo(cursorX, cursorY);
        recordedLines.forEach(parseRecordedLine);
    },
    false
);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="600" style="border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have to use all those points for what you’re working on but here’s a simplified version.

```
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 500;
canvas.height = 500;

let mouse = {
   x: null,
   y: null,
}

window.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  mouse.x = e.x;
  mouse.y = e.y;
  drawFace();
});

function drawFace() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(mouse.x, mouse.y, 5, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.arc(mouse.x + 30, mouse.y, 5, 0, Math.PI * 2);  
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
  
  ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
  ctx.lineWidth = 3;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(mouse.x + 14, mouse.y + 9, 30, 0.3, Math.PI / 1.1)
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath(); 
}
```

For your code you need to use `moveTo` when starting a new draw. lineTo will continue drawing from the previous point. moveTo picks up the pen and moves it to a new start location.

Comment: I'm trying to make it draw the smiley using the points from the variable.

Comment: You’ll need to use moveTo like I said above to stop your drawing from all being drawn connected to each other.

Comment: Justin, could you help me out with this. Instead of using a arc, is it possible to draw it from the array. My code draws the eyes in the same spot. I think it has to do something with making the coordinates relatively.

Comment: Sorta like your answer, but using the lines from the array.